# Can I output from Lightroom with zero padded numbered names for use in contact cards?

Tags: lightroom-4, windows, filenames

I use lightroom to export photos as it enabled you to use a sequential number, it looks like this:

Flower-1.jpg

The problem is that it doesn't seem to allow any preceding zeros so when I export them to contact cards, they list like this:

1,11,2,22,3,33...

Can I output these in Lightroom with zero padded names or am I stuck trying to so this in Windows directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually have them come out with proceeding zeros in Lightroom.

When you go to export, find the File Naming category. From there, make sure "Rename to" is checked and hit the drop down box. Select the last option "Edit...".

[image: Export image]

A box should come up allowing you to enter a formula for how files are named. For numeric sequences it should look something like **{Sequence # (1)»}**.  (Note: I couldn't copy and paste the double arrow, so I'm not entirely sure the one I'm using is exactly the same)

[image: Edit file naming window]

You can add preceding zeros to the number inside the parenthesis to get the effect you want.

For instance, I use this: **{Date (YYYYMMDD)»}-{Sequence # (001)»}**
So my files come out named like...
20140928-001.jpg,
20140928-002.jpg,
etc.

[image]

Comment: That did it, I didn't realise there was the edit function.

Answer (score 1):

In Lightroom go to File > Export (Ctrl+Shift+E)

[image]

Then check "Rename to" and choose custom settings

[image]

Clear out the text box and select the type of sequence you want from the drop down menu and insert. You can see the example as to how it'd appear. Select what you like and click 'Done'.